# domnode can not be written into xml in matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, dom

I read an xml file with xmlread in matlab . I want to modify some parts and write and xml file agian. 
The reading part goes well but when I even try to write same DOMnode created by "xmlread", I will get an error.
"Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
Error in xmlwrite>xmlWriteHelper (line 165)
            if ~publicId.isEmpty()"

any idea how to slove this ?

Thanks in advance,
Mojtaba

Answer (score 0):

I installed 2019b and now it works. Tried with 2018b and 2019a before and had the error.
Must be a bug in previous versions.

/Jesper